# specific url in email msg body classic ASP blocked but no blocks on mxtoolbox detected

Tags: javascript, html, smtp

My brother in law has a basic website (maltawide.eu) which was developed many years back in Classic ASP. It is probably overdue a rewrite but does not generate enough traffic to warrant it and he uses social media instead which works well.

Anyway the site has some functionality to recommend properties to other people which suddenly stopped working. It has happened before as it is on a shared IP with one of the sites is compromised and remains so not withstanding several reports/emails/posts to godaddy however mxtoolbox reported no issues with the maltwaide server.

As a side the url is  [http://bauerwhitetails.com/rx.html](http://%20http://bauerwhitetails.com/rx.html%20compromised)

The problem is that as you recommend properties, and you pass the url in the msg body which contains the url maltawide.eu it is blocked! I tested it with using other URLs and it works fine!

We have tried Godaddy's unblock functionality here https://unblock.secureserver.net/ but the domain/ip is not currently blocked!

One work around is to report the url and use a shortner (without the link to the property) or is it possibly to concatenate too?

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Here is an extract of the code:

```
<%
Option Explicit
%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft FrontPage 4.0">
<meta name="ProgId" content="FrontPage.Editor.Document">

<!--#INCLUDE FILE=includes/constants.inc-->
<!--#INCLUDE FILE=includes/functions.inc-->

<title>Maltawide Properties Limited</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/default.css">
</head>
<body link="#FFFFFF" vlink="#FFFFFF" alink="#FFFFFF">

<%

Dim objNewMail, sBody

Set objNewMail = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")
objNewMail.From = Request.Form("Your email address")
objNewMail.Cc = Request.Form("Your email address")
objNewMail.To   = Request.Form("Email to")
objNewMail.Subject = "Interesting property sent by " & Trim(Request.Form("Your name"))

sBody = Trim(Request.Form("Your name")) & " wants to show you an interesting property listed by " & vbcr & vbcr
sBody = sBody & "Maltawide Properties Ltd, Malta" & vbcr & vbcr
sBody = sBody & "Click the following link to see the property :" & vbcr & vbcr & "http://www.maltawide.eu/default.asp?pid=" & Request.Form("pid")

If Request.Form("Message") <> "" Then
    sBody = sBody & vbcr & vbcr & "Message from : " & Request.Form("Your Name") & vbcr & vbcr & Request.Form("Message")
End If

'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
objNewMail.TextBody = sBody

' GoDaddy SMTP Settings
objNewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing")=2
objNewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver")="relay-hosting.secureserver.net"
objNewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport")=25 
objNewMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60
objNewMail.Configuration.Fields.Update
objNewMail.Send

'After the Send method, NewMail Object become Invalid
'You should set it to nothing to release the memory

Set objNewMail = Nothing
```

Comment: What do you mean by blocked?  If the issue is with the GoDaddy SMTP server then this isn't a Classic ASP or a Javascript issue, it's an SMTP issue. (and your Classic ASP VBScript code looks absolutely fine).  One thing you can try is adding SSL authentication to your outgoing email, see this question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13531934/sending-a-cdo-email-message-using-an-ssl-connection

Comment: By blocked I mean that the email does not go through. As mentioned earlier in the thread, godaddy have a facility to check if the account is blocked but it does not seem to be the case. Also I do not think it is an authentication error as if I remove the maltawide.eu from the url it will work fine.

Comment: So you're not getting an error page when you try to send, the message is just not reaching its destination. It sounds like it's being treated as spam.  How many email addresses have you tried sending it to, and maybe this is a silly question, but if your own email account has a spam folder have you checked it's not showing up there?

Comment: That is correct - no email being sent out and no error message! Here is an test of  the routine to showing there is no coding issue http://maltawide.eu/cdo_mail.asp if I then edit the msg body to include maltawide.eu the email does not go through (as maltawid.eu it works!)

Comment: update the little proggy to include the text body - if you include maltawide.eu it fails (without errors) otherwise will work so clearly the domain (not IP) is somehow blocking it.

Comment: I see what you mean.  My best guess is that your hosting provider has an anti spam policy in place which filters out any message containing the domain of the site being hosted.  If this is the case then the only people who can help you are the tech support team of your hosting provider.  As I suggested earlier you may need to look into using an alternative SMTP server.